# Using 'SEARCH' or 'PATCH' with jetty

Tags: java, jetty

This basically has me at a loss, and has for almost a week. I'm working on a part of company architecture, trying to get REST all set up. There are two methods that are not in the javax.ws.rs package - SEARCH and PATCH. I've created the following interface in our project to implement SEARCH: (mostly a copy/paste from examples)

```
/** imports and such as appropriate **/
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@HttpMethod("SEARCH")
public @interface SEARCH {

}
```

The code using this works flawlessly if called against it directly. However, the web service that talks to the main service fails every time with `500 Invalid HTTP method: SEARCH`. So, to be clear, there are two web-enabled services. The first that uses the above code works fine. The second, which is supposed to be nothing but a proxy to the first service fails.

The second service that is having the problem runs on jetty. The servlet that is doing the proxying is an extension of org.mortbay.servlet.ProxyServlet - the only overrides are on init and proxyHttpUrl to do a little bit of URL tweaking. I know that the second service doesn't pass the response into the first because I can shut down the first and the second still gives me that error back.

My question is, am I missing configuration pieces to enable "custom" (i.e. not in the javax.ws.rs package) http methods?

Answer (score 1):

First off, that proxy servlet code is very old, from jetty-6 unless I am mistaken.  We have released jetty-9 now, and the last three versions of jetty have come from eclipse so the ProxyServlet you ought to be using is the org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.ProxyServlet class.

Now, from jetty-7 on we added some customization to that proxy servlet so you could modify much more of the client exchange...and you might need to make use of that to get additional http methods working.  It could be that the http-client only excepts standard http methods in which case we would have to fix that up for your use case ([open a bug at bugs.eclipse.org under RT/Jetty](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Jetty&format=guided) if that is the case).